# Reverse Geocoding using Java in localhost

Tags: java, google-maps

I am trying to Reverse Geo code using Java But unable to as i am getting a Connection time out .The program is running on locahost:8080 and it gives me connectiion time out . Please let me know the issue .Thanks in advance

The Program is as follows

```
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;

public class ReverseGeo {
public static void main(String ar[]) throws Exception {
System.out.println(new ReverseGeo().getAddress("13.031067,80.239656"));
}
public String getAddress(String latlong){

String address = null;
String gURL = "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?latlng=" + latlong + "&sensor=true";

try {
DocumentBuilderFactory df = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder db = df.newDocumentBuilder();
Document dom = db.parse(gURL);
Element docEl = dom.getDocumentElement();
NodeList nl = docEl.getElementsByTagName("result");
if (nl != null && nl.getLength() > 0){
address=((Element)nl.item(0)).getElementsByTagName("formatted_address").item(0).getTextContent();
for(int i=0;i<nl.getLength();i++){
String temp=((Element)nl.item(i)).getElementsByTagName("formatted_address").item(0).getTextContent();
}
}
} catch (Exception ex) {

    System.out.println("Error"+ex);
address = "Err";
}
return address;
}
public String getAddress(String lat, String lon) {
return getAddress(lat+ "," + lon);
}
public String getAddress(double lat, double lon) {
return getAddress("" + lat, "" + lon);
}
}
```

And the error is

```
Errorjava.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
Err
```

Answer (score 0):

add the below code into ur code ..there will be  no error

```
System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", " proxy name");
System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", " Port number");
```